# I have to draw this graph by tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

How to draw this graph by TikZ?

[image]

Comment: You can create this graph by TikZ by writing TikZ code that describes it...

Comment: Welcome! Why do you have to do it with TikZ? What have you tried? Generally, it is not really fair to post an image and expect somebody else to do everything for. That's not to say you won't get an answer. You may. Especially if the image is attractive or makes an interesting challenge. But you are less likely to get help because you are not really asking for help. You aren't stuck. You just want somebody else to do it. And it is harder to help: takes longer, is less interesting, is less likely to actually help effectively etc.

Comment: Excuse me, I d'ont mean waht ou are said, I just have to draw this image and I didn't work by tikz before ,exucuse me another time.

Comment: @BahouliBassem Apology accepted, but where is the code?  What is even your question?  Yes, this picture can be made using TikZ.

Comment: If you just need to use the picture and you don't know TikZ, you can just draw it in the application of your choice and use `\includegraphics{}` from the `graphicx` package.

Comment: @HenriMenke Isn't it a bit quick to put it on hold when it is the OP's first question? Especially since they only joined the site today. I agree the question needs improvement, but it hasn't been given much time to be improved. Of course, it can be re-opened, but doesn't this site generally have a policy of not closing too quickly in this kind of case?

Comment: Please reopen, I have spent lot of time for an answer.

Comment: @HeikoOberdiek Sorry: I saw your comment only after having voted no...

Comment: @BahouliBassem Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 13):

The points for the Voronoi diagram are the vertices of the dashed lines. The outer points are named `A` to `I` the two thick points are named `K` and `L`.
The positions are extracted from the image by putting the cropped image in the background and putting a grid on it. The final document should not have the grid, thus it can be enabled by `\gridtrue` for the development phase.

Each dashed triangle is drawn separately. The coordinates for the circumcenter is calculated using a formula found in [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates_2) and
the circumcenter is named with the tree points of the triangle.

Since the triangles are touching each other, the drawn dashed lines are remembered in a macro to avoid drawing the same line twice.

The middle points of the dashed lines are named with the two end points of the line. Then the solid lines are drawn inside the triangle.

The outer exceed lines are also drawn, by defining, which lines they are crossing beforehand.

The position of the squares also needs some calculation, because they are set at the crossing of dashed with solid lines. TikZ library `intersections` helps here.

Full example:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\usetikzlibrary{intersections}
\usepackage{fp}
\usetikzlibrary{fixedpointarithmetic}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\newif\ifgrid
%\gridtrue

\makeatletter
\newcommand*{\Triangle}[3]{%
  \DashLine{#1}{#2}%
  \DashLine{#2}{#3}%
  \DashLine{#3}{#1}%
  \coordinate (#1#2) at ($(#1)!.5!(#2)$);
  \coordinate (#2#3) at ($(#2)!.5!(#3)$);
  \coordinate (#3#1) at ($(#3)!.5!(#1)$);
  % https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle#Cartesian_coordinates_2
  \draw[red, thick, fixed point arithmetic] let
    \p{A}=(#1),
    \p{B}=(#2),
    \p{C}=(#3),
    \n{D}={%
      2 * (
        \x{A}*(\y{B}-\y{C}) + \x{B}*(\y{C}-\y{A}) + \x{C}*(\y{A}-\y{B})
      )},
    \n{x}={%
      (
        (\x{A}*\x{A} + \y{A}*\y{A}) * (\y{B}-\y{C}) +
        (\x{B}*\x{B} + \y{B}*\y{B}) * (\y{C}-\y{A}) +
        (\x{C}*\x{C} + \y{C}*\y{C}) * (\y{A}-\y{B})
      ) / \n{D}},
    \n{y}={%
      (
        (\x{A}*\x{A} + \y{A}*\y{A}) * (\x{C}-\x{B}) +
        (\x{B}*\x{B} + \y{B}*\y{B}) * (\x{A}-\x{C}) +
        (\x{C}*\x{C} + \y{C}*\y{C}) * (\x{B}-\x{A})
      ) / \n{D}}
    in
     (\n{x}, \n{y}) coordinate (#1#2#3)
      (#1#2#3)
      \@ifundefined{L@#1#2}{%
        -- (#1#2)%
      }{%
        -- ($(#1#2)!-15pt!(#1#2#3)$)%
      }
      (#1#2#3) -- (#2#3)
      (#1#2#3) -- (#3#1)
  ;%
}
\newcommand*{\DashLine}[2]{%
  \@ifundefined{dd@#1#2}{%
    \draw[densely dashed, blue] (#1) -- (#2);%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname dd@#1#2\endcsname=1%
    \global\expandafter\let\csname dd@#2#1\endcsname=1%
  }{}%
}
\newdimen\dimSq
\setlength{\dimSq}{3pt}
\newcommand*{\Square}[3]{%
  \draw
    ($(#1)!#2!(#3)$) coordinate (sq1)
    ($(sq1)!\dimSq!0:(#3)$) coordinate (sq2)
    ($(sq2)!\dimSq!-90:(#3)$) coordinate (sq3)
    ($(sq1)!\dimSq!-90:(#3)$) coordinate (sq4)
    (sq1) -- (sq2) -- (sq3) -- (sq4) -- cycle
  ;%
}
\newcommand*{\SquareM}[4]{%
  \path[name path=lineA] (#1) -- (#2);
  \path[name path=lineB] (#3) -- (#4);
  \draw[
    name intersections={of=lineA and lineB, name=cross},
  ]
    ($(cross-1)!\dimSq!0:(#2)$) coordinate (sq2)
    ($(sq2)!\dimSq!90:(#2)$) coordinate (sq3)
    ($(cross-1)!\dimSq!90:(#2)$) coordinate (sq4)
    (cross-1) -- (sq2) -- (sq3) -- (sq4) -- cycle
  ;
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\setlength{\unitlength}{.75mm}
\begin{tikzpicture}[x=\unitlength, y=\unitlength]

  \ifgrid
    \node[above right, inner sep=0pt]
      (img) {\includegraphics[width=100\unitlength]{D27KN-crop.png}};
    \draw[ultra thin, gray, step=1\unitlength]
      (img.south west) grid (img.north east);
    \draw[thin, red, step=10\unitlength]
      (img.south west) grid (img.north east);
  \fi

  \coordinate (A) at (94, 62);
  \coordinate (B) at (73, 86);
  \coordinate (C) at (38, 82);
  \coordinate (D) at (15, 61);
  \coordinate (E) at ( 7, 34);
  \coordinate (F) at (22, 10);
  \coordinate (G) at (48,  1);
  \coordinate (H) at (76,  8);
  \coordinate (I) at (86, 27);
  \coordinate (K) at (62, 53);
  \coordinate (L) at (46, 27);

  \fill[radius=1pt] \foreach \P in {A, ..., I} {(\P) circle[]};
  \fill[radius=2pt] (K) circle[] (L) circle[];

  \foreach \L in {AB, BC, CD, DE, EF, FG, GH, HI, IA}
  {\global\expandafter\let\csname L@\L\endcsname=1 }

  \foreach \T in {ABK, BCK, CDK, DEL, EFL, FGL, GHL, HIL, IAK, LKD, LIK}
  {\expandafter\Triangle\T}

  \path
    (K)   -- node[pos=.75] {$K$} (ABK)
    (K)   -- node[pos=.35] {$\mathbf{x}_K$} (IAK)
    (LK)  -- node[pos=.55] {$S$} (I)
    (L)   -- node[pos=.3] {$\mathbf{x}_L$} (GH)
    (L)   -- node[pos=.4] {$L$} (EF)
    (LKD) -- node[pos=.4, above] {$e$} (LIK)
  ;
  \draw[-{LaTeX}]
    ($(LKD)!.65!(LIK)$) coordinate (tmp)
    (tmp) -- ($(tmp)!15pt!90:(LKD)$)
    node[below right, yshift=1ex] {$\mathbf{n}_{K,e}$}
  ;
  \Square{LKD}{.65}{LIK}
  \SquareM{LIK}{IAK}IK
  \SquareM{IAK}{ABK}AK
  \SquareM{ABK}{BCK}BK
  \SquareM{BCK}{CDK}CK
  \SquareM{CDK}{LKD}DK
  \path[lightgray, node font=\scriptsize]
    \foreach \P/\N in {
      A/right,
      B/above,
      C/above left,
      D/left,
      E/left,
      F/below left,
      G/below,
      H/below right,
      I/right%
    } { (\P) node[\N] {\P} }
  ;

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

> [image: Result]

Answer (score 3):

Run with `xelatex` or `latex->dvips->ps2pdf`

```
\documentclass{scrartcl}
\usepackage{pst-eucl,pst-math}
\begin{document}

\psset{unit=1mm}
\begin{pspicture}(100,100)
\pstGeonode[PosAngle={10,45,90,110,170,200,-90,-45,0,-90,90}]%
  (94, 62){A}(73, 86){B}(38, 82){C}(15, 61){D}( 7, 34){E}%
  (22, 10){F}(48,  1){G}(76,  8){H}(86, 27){I}(62, 53){K}(46, 27){L}
\end{pspicture}
\psset{linestyle=dashed,linecolor=blue}
\pspolygon(A)(B)(C)(D)(E)(F)(G)(H)(I)
\psline(B)(K)(L)(G)\psline(H)(L)(E)\psline(I)(L)(D)\psline(I)(K)(D)
\psline(C)(K)(A)\psline(L)(F)
\psset{PointSymbol=none,PointName=none,linestyle=none}
\pstCircleABC{A}{B}{K}{M0} \pstCircleABC{B}{C}{K}{M1}% Mx intersection point
\pstCircleABC{C}{D}{K}{M2} \pstCircleABC{D}{L}{K}{M3}
\pstCircleABC{D}{E}{L}{M4} \pstCircleABC{E}{F}{L}{M5}
\pstCircleABC{F}{G}{L}{M6} \pstCircleABC{G}{H}{L}{M7}
\pstCircleABC{H}{I}{L}{M8} \pstCircleABC{I}{K}{L}{M9}
\pstCircleABC{I}{A}{K}{M10}
\psset{linestyle=solid,linecolor=red,linewidth=1pt}
\pspolygon(M9)(M10)(M0)(M1)(M2)(M3)
\psline(M3)(M4)(M5)(M6)(M7)(M8)(M9)
\pstMiddleAB{A}{B}{AB}\pstMiddleAB{B}{C}{BC}
\pstMiddleAB{C}{D}{CD}\pstMiddleAB{D}{E}{DE}
\pstMiddleAB{E}{F}{EF}\pstMiddleAB{F}{G}{FG}
\pstMiddleAB{G}{H}{GH}\pstMiddleAB{H}{I}{HI}
\pstMiddleAB{I}{A}{IA}
\psset{nodesepA=-10}
\pcline(AB)(M0)\pcline(BC)(M1)\pcline(CD)(M2)
\pcline(DE)(M4)\pcline(EF)(M5)\pcline(FG)(M6)
\pcline(GH)(M7)\pcline(HI)(M8)\pcline(IA)(M10)
\uput[-80](L){$x_L$}\uput[190](K){$x_K$}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Use `\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}`

```
%\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate[label=left:$X_k$](O) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=$A2$](A2) at ($(O)+(10:3)$);
\coordinate[label=$A3$](A3) at ($(O)+(45:3)$);
\coordinate[label=$A4$](A4) at ($(O)+(100:3)$);
\coordinate(C5) at ($(O)+(160:4)$);
\coordinate[label=left:$X_L$](K) at ($(O)+(220:3)$);
 \coordinate(C1) at ($(O)+(-60:4)$);
 \coordinate(B1) at ($(K)+(110:4)$);
 \coordinate[label=$B2$](B2) at ($(K)+(170:3)$);
 \coordinate[label=$B3$](B3) at ($(K)+(220:3)$);
 \coordinate[label=$B4$](B4) at ($(K)+(-90:3)$);
 \coordinate[label=$B5$](B5) at ($(K)+(-45:3.5)$);
 \coordinate(B7) at ($(K)+(-10:2)$);
 \fill(O)circle (1mm);
 \fill(K)circle (1mm);
 \coordinate[label=$A5$] (A5) at (intersection cs:first line={(O)--(C5)}, second line={(K)--(B1)});
 \coordinate[label=$A5$] (B1) at (intersection cs:first line={(O)--(C5)}, second line={(K)--(B1)});
 \coordinate[label=$A1$] (A1) at (intersection cs:first line={(O)--(C1)}, second line={(K)--(B7)});
 \coordinate(B6) at (intersection cs:first line={(O)--(C1)}, second line={(K)--(B7)});
 \begin{scope}[dashed,blue]
 \draw (A1)--(A2)--(A3)--(A4)--(A5)--(B2)--(B3)--(B4)--(B5)--cycle;
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5}
  {
 \draw (O)--(A\x);
}
\foreach \x in {1,2,3,4,5,6}
  {
 \draw (K)--(B\x);
}
 \draw (O)--(K);
\end{scope}
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5}
 {
\coordinate(M\i) at ($(O)!0.5!(A\i)$);
 }
 \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5,6}
 {
 \coordinate(X\i) at ($(K)!0.5!(B\i)$);
 }
%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%%
 \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5}
 {
 \coordinate(L\i) at  ($(M\i)!2cm!90:(A\i)$);
}
 \coordinate (T1) at (intersection cs:first line={(M1)--(L1)}, second line={(M2)--(L2)});
 \coordinate (T2) at (intersection cs:first line={(M2)--(L2)}, second line={(M3)--(L3)});
 \coordinate (T3) at (intersection cs:first line={(M3)--(L3)}, second line={(M4)--(L4)});
 \coordinate (T4) at (intersection cs:first line={(M4)--(L4)}, second line={(M5)--(L5)});

 \foreach \i in {1,2,3,4,5,6}
 {
 \coordinate(H\i) at  ($(X\i)!2cm!90:(B\i)$);
}
\coordinate (T5) at (intersection cs:first line={(M5)--(L5)}, second line={(X1)--(H1)});
\coordinate (T6) at (intersection cs:first line={(X1)--(H1)}, second line={(X2)--(H2)});
\coordinate (T7) at (intersection cs:first line={(X2)--(H2)}, second line={(X3)--(H3)});
\coordinate (T8) at (intersection cs:first line={(X3)--(H3)}, second line={(X4)--(H4)});
\coordinate (T9) at (intersection cs:first line={(X4)--(H4)}, second line={(X5)--(H5)});
\coordinate (T10)at (intersection cs:first line={(X5)--(H5)}, second line={(X6)--(H6)});
\coordinate (T11)at (intersection cs:first line={(M1)--(L1)}, second line={(X6)--(H6)});
\begin{scope}[red,very thick]
\draw(T1)--(T2)--(T3)--(T4)--(T5)--(T6)--(T7)--(T8)--(T9)--(T10)--(T11)--cycle;
\draw(T5)--(T11);
\coordinate (E1) at ($(A1)!0.5!(A2)$);
\coordinate (E2) at ($(A2)!0.5!(A3)$);
\coordinate (E3) at ($(A3)!0.5!(A4)$);
\coordinate (E4) at ($(A4)!0.5!(A5)$);
\coordinate (E5) at ($(A5)!0.5!(B2)$);
\coordinate (E6) at ($(B2)!0.5!(B3)$);
\coordinate (E7) at ($(B3)!0.5!(B4)$);
\coordinate (E8) at ($(B4)!0.5!(B5)$);
\coordinate (E9) at ($(B5)!0.5!(B6)$);
\draw(T1)--($(T1)!2!(E1)$);
\draw(T2)--($(T2)!2!(E2)$);
\draw(T3)--($(T3)!2!(E3)$);
\draw(T4)--($(T4)!2!(E4)$);
\draw(T6)--($(T6)!2!(E5)$);
\draw(T7)--($(T7)!2!(E6)$);
\draw(T8)--($(T8)!2!(E7)$);
\draw(T9)--($(T9)!2!(E8)$);
\draw(T10)--($(T10)!2!(E9)$);
\end{scope}
\node  at (0.5,1) {$K$};
\node  at (-3,-1) {$L$};
 \coordinate(S) at  ($(T11)!.40!(T5)$);
 \coordinate(S1) at  ($(S)!1cm!90:(T5)$);
\draw[->,thick](S)--node[below,sloped]{$n_{k,e}$}(S1);

\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Comment: If you recommend to use `\usetikzlibrary{intersections,calc}` it shouldn't be commented out ;-) Please provide a compilable code, not just a fragment